# SASS @each function providing cleaner CSS?

Tags: css, sass

I have the following SASS `@each`:

```
$obj-list: 1, 2, 3

.object
   @each $obj in $obj-list
      &:nth-child(#{$obj})
         color: #fff
```

But ir generates the following:

```
.object:nth-child(1){
    color: #fff
}
.object:nth-child(2){
    color: #fff
}
.object:nth-child(3){
    color: #fff
}
```

How can I make this generate a cleaner CSS?

```
.object:nth-child(1), .object:nth-child(2), .object:nth-child(3){
    color: #fff
}
```

---

Check it out here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lgbok

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want it that way, the output of sass is not really create with focus for readbility?

Comment: @t.niese the desired output is much shorter. There's no reason not to create efficient CSS whenever possible.

Comment: @NilsKaspersson I cannot confirm or falsify that it would be more efficient, but for the browser (except that they a listed as different rules in the stylesheet) the selectors need to be tested and applied separately anyway so i don't think that is a difference in efficient. If it is about size, it may be smaller if compress but not necessarily. So I would be more concerned if the sass file itself is clearer for reading and maintaining. And use a good caching technique.

Comment: @t.niese It's a good practice. I don't think adding an `@extend` makes it any less readable. Again - there's no reason not to do this.

Comment: @NilsKaspersson Whether if it is good practice or not for a production output is opinion based. But personally I suggest not to add a _unnecessary layer of complexity_ in the developmental code if it is just to _prettify_ the production output and is not necessary to increate readability of the developmental code. If it is required to format the output that way I would suggest a post processing step and using a tool like `clean-css` or similar. Anyway it is opinion based as I said and up to the reader to choose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution would be to `extend` a [silent class](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_).

```
$obj-list: 1, 2, 3

%object
  color: #f00

.object
  @each $obj in $obj-list
    &:nth-child(#{$obj})
      @extend %object
```

[Here's a fork of your pen](http://codepen.io/Mest/pen/JICBm).

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to use the following:

```
$selectors: ()
$obj-list: 1, 2, 3 

@each $obj in $obj-list
  $selectors: $selectors, unquote(".object:nth-child(#{$obj})")

#{$selectors}
  color: #f00
```

See it in action in this fork of your original codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iDJfx

This is based on the technique suggested by this blog post: http://roytomeij.com/blog/2012/using-each-in-sass-to-create-selectors.html. The author of the blog post is correct in that this approach isn't totally elegant, but it does get the job done nicely.